# C++ amp atomics

Tags: c++, atomic, c++-amp

I am rewriting an algorithm in C++ AMP and just ran into an issue with atomic writes, more specifically atomic_fetch_add, which apparently is only for integers?

I need to add a double_4 (or if I have to, a float_4) in an atomic fashion. How do I accomplish that with C++ AMP's atomics?

Is the best/only solution really to have a lock variable which my code can use to control the writes? I actually need to do atomic writes for a long list of output doubles, so I would essentially need a lock for every output.

I have already considered tiling this for better performance, but right now I am just in the first iteration.

EDIT:
Thanks for the quick answers already given.
I have a quick update to my question though.

I made the following lock attempt, but it seems that when one thread in a warp gets past the lock, all the other threads in the same warp just tags along. I was expecting the first warp thread to get the lock, but I must be missing something (note that it has been quite a few years since my cuda days, so I have just gotten dumb)

```
parallel_for_each(attracting.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
   .....
   for (int j = 0; j < attracted.extent.size(); j++)
   {
      ...
      int lock = 0; //the expected lock value
      while (!atomic_compare_exchange(&locks[j], &lock, 1));
      //when one warp thread gets the lock, ALL threads continue on
      ...
      acceleration[j] += ...; //locked write
      locks[j] = 0; //leaving the lock again
   }
});
```

It is as such not a big problem, since I should write into a shared variable at first and only write it to global memory after all threads in a tile have completed, but I just don't understand this behavior.

Comment: according to the following link there is no issue with adding floats or doubles, which issue you had? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp121.linux.doc%2Fcompiler_ref%2Fbif_gcc_atomic_add_fetch.html

Comment: Atomic ops are generally not something that is supported natively. Although the use of `T*` in the docs seeems to suggest otherwise, you probably need to read the variable (from a type-punned pointer), modify it, and do a compare-exchange, again on a type-punned integer pointer. When they say `T`, they most likely mean "any integer T", not "any T".

Comment: Regarding your edit - did you give each thread its own lock? How would they be mutually exclusive then?

Comment: Locks is global. One lock per contended write position. Each thread should therefore try to get the same lock j before writing to j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has as such been answered by others and the answer is that you need to handle double atomics yourself. There is no function for it in the library.

I would also like to elaborate on my own edit, in case others come here with the same failing lock.

In the following example, my error was in not realizing that when the exchange failed, it actually changed the expected value! Thus the first thread would expect lock being zero and write a 1 in it. The next thread would expect 0 and would fail to write a one - but then the exchange wrote a one in the variable holding the *expected* value. This means that the next time the thread tried to do an exchange it expects a 1 in the lock! This it gets and then it thinks it gets the lock.

I was absolutely not aware that the &lock would receive a 1 on failed exchange match!

```
parallel_for_each(attracting.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
   .....
   for (int j = 0; j < attracted.extent.size(); j++)
   {
      ...
      int lock = 0; //the expected lock value

      **//note that, if locks[j]!=lock then lock=1
      //meaning that ACE will be true the next time if locks[j]==1
      //meaning the while will terminate even though someone else has the lock**
      while (!atomic_compare_exchange(&locks[j], &lock, 1));
      //when one warp thread gets the lock, ALL threads continue on
      ...
      acceleration[j] += ...; //locked write
      locks[j] = 0; //leaving the lock again
   }
});
```

It seems that a fix is to do

```
parallel_for_each(attracting.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
   .....
   for (int j = 0; j < attracted.extent.size(); j++)
   {
      ...
      int lock = 0; //the expected lock value

      while (!atomic_compare_exchange(&locks[j], &lock, 1))
      {
          lock=0; //reset the expected value
      };
      //when one warp thread gets the lock, ALL threads continue on
      ...
      acceleration[j] += ...; //locked write
      locks[j] = 0; //leaving the lock again
   }
});
```

Comment: A better fix is to use atomic_exchange which doesn't change the "expectation"

Answer (score 2):

All the atomic add ops are only for integer types. You can do what you want without locks using 128-bit CAS (compare-and-swap) operations though for float_4 (I'm assuming this is 4 floats), but there's no 256-bit CAS ops what you would need for double_4. What you have to do is to have a loop which atomically reads float_4 from memory, perform the float add in the regular way, and then use CAS to test & swap the value if it's the original (and loop if not, i.e. some other thread changed the value between read & write). Note that the 128-bit CAS is only available on 64-bit architectures and that your data needs to be properly aligned.

Comment: At first it seemed wasteful to loop with a read, compare and write like you suggested, but I guess it as good as looping while trying to get a lock.

I do wonder, though, what you think about this implementation:

while (!atomic_compare_exchange(&locks[j], &lock, 1));
acceleration[j] += acc; //write to contended address
locks[j] = 0; //clear lock

Where I have an array_View of int same length as the acceleration array_view...?

Comment: @JoeTaicoonless What I proposed is a common pattern used in lock-free programming. The difference is that with lock-free implementation like I proposed there's always some progress happening in the system. In the implementation you proposed, the system might just stall the executing thread in the middle of addition and other threads are forced to wait for the completion (i.e. releasing the lock).

Comment: so in case of the lock is already taken by another thread you can suspend the thread by yield operation instead of busy waiting

Comment: You could but it still prevents progress in the system. Depending on your case this may not be a feasible way to avoid stalling.

Answer (score 1):

if the critical code is short, you can create your own lock using atomic operations:

```
int lock = 1;

while(__sync_lock_test_and_set(&lock, 0) == 0) // trying to acquire lock
{
 //yield the thread or go to sleep
} 

//critical section, do the work

// release lock
lock = 1;
```

the advantage is you save the overhead of the OS locks.

Comment: I don't think that is available in C++ AMP?

Comment: what isn't available in C++ AMP? you can use any compare and swap method you have instead of __sync_lock_test_and_set

Comment: Sorry, simply assumed it was a specific library method you were referring to. As it turns out, your suggestion is then exactly what I tried just now. Please see the edit in my question for the details.